# css:Multiple effects cause the rollover to be invalid

Tags: html, css

I have an input[type='button'] element that needs to be flipped.

When using transform: scale(-1,1), it can be displayed correctly.

However, when I add other effects (ex: transform: scale(-1,-1) tranlate(0px,0px)), I can't flip it properly. What is the reason?

Comment: Please include your code in the question, and ideally make a small demo for us to help

Answer (score 0):

Check this >>> i think you miss a letter translate() try to validate your code to see what's wrong with it.
I will recommend you to go https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_inpu.
i hope this was helpful.